# How to repeat rows with 0 price from dataframe before non zero price row?

Tags: r

I have a data

```
   WEEK PRICE QUANTITY SALE_PRICE
   4992  3.49 1908.750       0.00
   4999  2.50 5681.000       2.50
   5001  3.00 3187.000       3.00
   5002  3.49 1455.000       0.00
   5008  2.69 2263.500       2.69
   5011  3.49 1515.500       0.00
   5013  2.69 3297.000       2.69
   5015  3.49 1059.500       0.00
   5023  2.50 6056.000       2.50
   5024  3.00 1954.500       3.00
   5026  3.49 1163.833       0.00
   5037  2.50 6797.000       2.50
   5038  3.00 2109.000       3.00
   5040  2.50 4521.000       2.50
   5041  3.33 2469.000       3.33
```

I want to repeat the last observed row with sale price 0, immediately before a non zero sale price only at the places where there is no row with sale price 0 before a row having a sale price. The output should look like this:

```
  WEEK PRICE QUANTITY SALE_PRICE TYPE
  4992  3.49 1908.750       0.00    3
  4999  2.50 5681.000       2.50    3
  4992  3.49 1908.750       0.00    3
  5001  3.00 3187.000       3.00    3
  5002  3.49 1455.000       0.00    3
  5008  2.69 2263.500       2.69    3
  5011  3.49 1515.500       0.00    3
  5013  2.69 3297.000       2.69    3
  5015  3.49 1059.500       0.00    3
  5023  2.50 6056.000       2.50    3
  5015  3.49 1059.500       0.00    3
  5024  3.00 1954.500       3.00    3
  5026  3.49 1163.833       0.00    3
  5037  2.50 6797.000       2.50    3
  5026  3.49 1163.833       0.00    3
  5038  3.00 2109.000       3.00    3
  5026  3.49 1163.833       0.00    3
  5040  2.50 4521.000       2.50    3
  5026  3.49 1163.833       0.00    3
  5041  3.33 2469.000       3.33    3
```

Data

```
structure(list(WEEK = c(4992L, 4999L, 5001L, 5002L, 5008L, 5011L, 
5013L, 5015L, 5023L, 5024L, 5026L, 5037L, 5038L, 5040L, 5041L
), PRICE = c(3.49, 2.5, 3, 3.49, 2.69, 3.49, 2.69, 3.49, 2.5, 
3, 3.49, 2.5, 3, 2.5, 3.33), QUANTITY = c(1908.75, 5681, 3187, 
1455, 2263.5, 1515.5, 3297, 1059.5, 6056, 1954.5, 1163.833, 6797, 
2109, 4521, 2469), SALE_PRICE = c(0, 2.5, 3, 0, 2.69, 0, 2.69, 
0, 2.5, 3, 0, 2.5, 3, 2.5, 3.33)), .Names = c("WEEK", "PRICE", 
"QUANTITY", "SALE_PRICE"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

I have tried

```
 if(nrow(price.hierarchy) > 2) {
  for(i in 2: (nrow(price.hierarchy) - 1)) {
      if(price.hierarchy$SALE_PRICE[i] !=0 & price.hierarchy$SALE_PRICE[i+1] !=0 & price.hierarchy$SALE_PRICE[i-1]==0) {
        price.hierarchy1 <- price.hierarchy[which(price.hierarchy[, 1] > price.hierarchy[i,1]), ]
        price.hierarchy[i+1, ] <- NA 
        price.hierarchy[i+1, ] <- price.hierarchy[i-1, ]
        price.hierarchy2 <- price.hierarchy[which(price.hierarchy[, 1] < price.hierarchy[i+2,1]), ] 
        price.hierarchy <- rbind(price.hierarchy2, price.hierarchy1)        
      }
      else 
        price.hierarchy
    }
  }
```

Which gives:

```
> price.hierarchy
    WEEK PRICE QUANTITY SALE_PRICE
1   4992  3.49 1908.750       0.00
2   4999  2.50 5681.000       2.50
3   4992  3.49 1908.750       0.00
31  5001  3.00 3187.000       3.00
4   5002  3.49 1455.000       0.00
5   5008  2.69 2263.500       2.69
6   5011  3.49 1515.500       0.00
7   5013  2.69 3297.000       2.69
8   5015  3.49 1059.500       0.00
9   5023  2.50 6056.000       2.50
10  5015  3.49 1059.500       0.00
101 5024  3.00 1954.500       3.00
11  5026  3.49 1163.833       0.00
12  5037  2.50 6797.000       2.50
13  5026  3.49 1163.833       0.00
131 5038  3.00 2109.000       3.00
14  5040  2.50 4521.000       2.50
15  5041  3.33 2469.000       3.33
```

Comment: Did you try anything? SO is not a free code writing service. We can help you if you get stuck along the way so please show what you've done so far

Comment: expecetd output is not ordered by week. So order by would not use after rbind

Answer (score 1):

The `shift` function from `data.table` could be useful here.

> I want to repeat last observed row with sale price 0, immediate before
>   non zero sale price only at the places where there is no row with sale
>   price 0 before a row having sale price

I'm not sure about the latter requirements without more explanation. Here's a quick solution that gives the observations an identifier `i` for sorting purposes, and then duplicates and appends those that precede a zero sale price. Finally, sort on identifiers adjusted to place duplicated rows two rows after the originals.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(d)
d[, i := seq_len(.N)]
d[, led_zero := shift(SALE_PRICE, type = "lead") == 0]
d_duped = d[(led_zero)][, i := i + 1.5]
d_out = rbind(d, d_duped)
d_out[order(i)]
#     WEEK PRICE QUANTITY SALE_PRICE    i led_zero
#  1: 4992  3.49 1908.750       0.00  1.0    FALSE
#  2: 4999  2.50 5681.000       2.50  2.0    FALSE
#  3: 5001  3.00 3187.000       3.00  3.0     TRUE
#  4: 5002  3.49 1455.000       0.00  4.0    FALSE
#  5: 5001  3.00 3187.000       3.00  4.5     TRUE
#  6: 5008  2.69 2263.500       2.69  5.0     TRUE
#  7: 5011  3.49 1515.500       0.00  6.0    FALSE
#  8: 5008  2.69 2263.500       2.69  6.5     TRUE
#  9: 5013  2.69 3297.000       2.69  7.0     TRUE
# 10: 5015  3.49 1059.500       0.00  8.0    FALSE
# 11: 5013  2.69 3297.000       2.69  8.5     TRUE
# 12: 5023  2.50 6056.000       2.50  9.0    FALSE
# 13: 5024  3.00 1954.500       3.00 10.0     TRUE
# 14: 5026  3.49 1163.833       0.00 11.0    FALSE
# 15: 5024  3.00 1954.500       3.00 11.5     TRUE
# 16: 5037  2.50 6797.000       2.50 12.0    FALSE
# 17: 5038  3.00 2109.000       3.00 13.0    FALSE
# 18: 5040  2.50 4521.000       2.50 14.0    FALSE
# 19: 5041  3.33 2469.000       3.33 15.0       NA
```

Comment: How can it be done "then duplicates and appends those that precede a zero sale price" I am not clear about the solution you gave.

Comment: That's rbind. Try printing to the console after each line.