# How to change data frame by getting some specific rows repeated?

Tags: r

```
    a      b     c             d
   5015  3.49 1059.500       0.00
   5023  2.50 6056.000       2.50
   5024  3.00 1954.500       3.00
   5026  3.49 1163.833       0.00
   5037  2.50 6797.000       2.50
   5038  3.00 2109.000       3.00
   5040  2.50 4521.000       2.50
   5041  3.33 2469.000       3.33
```

I want to repeat previously observed row with column 0 before a row non zero value of d. so, I will get rows with alternate rows of row with zero value of d then non zero value of d. a row with zero value of d must be previously observed row.

Output I want is:

```
   a     b    c              d      

  5015  3.49 1059.500       0.00    
  5023  2.50 6056.000       2.50    
  5015  3.49 1059.500       0.00    
  5024  3.00 1954.500       3.00    
  5026  3.49 1163.833       0.00    
  5037  2.50 6797.000       2.50    
  5026  3.49 1163.833       0.00    
  5038  3.00 2109.000       3.00    
  5026  3.49 1163.833       0.00    
  5040  2.50 4521.000       2.50    
  5026  3.49 1163.833       0.00    
  5041  3.33 2469.000       3.33
```

Comment: dont repost your questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019820/how-to-repeat-rows-with-0-price-from-dataframe-before-non-zero-price-row

Comment: I did not have a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a custom function `f` that will interleave the first row. Split on `cumsum(d == 0)` creating an index for values equaling 0. Finally we combine with `do.call(rbind, ...)`. I added an optional `'row.names<-'(..., NULL)` call to undo the default naming convention:

```
f <- function(x) x[c(rbind(rep(1,nrow(x)-1), 2:nrow(x))),]
`row.names<-`(do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df1, cumsum(df1$d == 0)), f)), NULL)
#       a    b        c    d
# 1  5015 3.49 1059.500 0.00
# 2  5023 2.50 6056.000 2.50
# 3  5015 3.49 1059.500 0.00
# 4  5024 3.00 1954.500 3.00
# 5  5026 3.49 1163.833 0.00
# 6  5037 2.50 6797.000 2.50
# 7  5026 3.49 1163.833 0.00
# 8  5038 3.00 2109.000 3.00
# 9  5026 3.49 1163.833 0.00
# 10 5040 2.50 4521.000 2.50
# 11 5026 3.49 1163.833 0.00
# 12 5041 3.33 2469.000 3.33
```

There is an interleave trick in there. Try `c(rbind(c(1,1,1), c(2,3,4)))` to see the way the numbers will be weaved together

Comment: Here are some other interleaving tricks, for folks' reference: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16443260/1191259

Answer (score 2):

Package data.table's grouping by is useful here:

```
library(data.table)
DF <-fread("    a      b     c             d
   5015  3.49 1059.500       0.00
                 5023  2.50 6056.000       2.50
                 5024  3.00 1954.500       3.00
                 5026  3.49 1163.833       0.00
                 5037  2.50 6797.000       2.50
                 5038  3.00 2109.000       3.00
                 5040  2.50 4521.000       2.50
                 5041  3.33 2469.000       3.33")

DF[ #find indices:
  DF[, {ind <- .I[rep(1L, (.N - 1) * 2)] #first repeat the first index
      ind[c(FALSE, TRUE)] <- .I[-1] #then replace every second repeat with the other indices
      ind
      }, by = cumsum(abs(d) < .Machine$double.eps^0.5)][["V1"]] #group by the different d = 0 rows, 
                                                                 #beware of floating point errors if you have calculated d
  ] #subset with the indices

#        a    b        c    d
#  1: 5015 3.49 1059.500 0.00
#  2: 5023 2.50 6056.000 2.50
#  3: 5015 3.49 1059.500 0.00
#  4: 5024 3.00 1954.500 3.00
#  5: 5026 3.49 1163.833 0.00
#  6: 5037 2.50 6797.000 2.50
#  7: 5026 3.49 1163.833 0.00
#  8: 5038 3.00 2109.000 3.00
#  9: 5026 3.49 1163.833 0.00
# 10: 5040 2.50 4521.000 2.50
# 11: 5026 3.49 1163.833 0.00
# 12: 5041 3.33 2469.000 3.33
```